# Where can I find the mon-* set of Amazon CloudWatch tools?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring

Once upon a time, based on the large quantity of websites saying that all I needed to install to administer Amazon services including CloudWatch and Auto-Scaling Groups was the "ec2-api-tools" package.  However, as I try to recreate some steps found in [pages like this](http://kkpradeeban.blogspot.com/2011/01/auto-scaling-with-amazon-ec2.html), I find I cannot succeed due to missing commands.

I'm assuming these commands were simply refactored, but searching for, e.g., mon-describe-alarms or mon-put-metric-alarm with apt-file yields no results.  It's as if someone decided, "Nawww...nobody will need these!" and removed them from ec2-api-tools with no substitution provided.

Does anyone know what happened, and/or where I can find an Ubuntu package for the  CloudWatch tools?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the most recent releases of CloudWatch software from Amazon are Java applications, and thus cross-platform.  Installing is as simple as downloading the .zip file from Amazon and unpacking it.  The lack of platform-specific configuration or compilation could well justify the removal of CloudWatch software from a package.

It's just a bit of a shock, especially without finding any kind of documentation on the matter.  Hopefully, answering my own question here will serve as some documentation for others in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the aws tools from amazon have made it into the Ubuntu archive.  Others have made it into the 'awstools-dev' ppa at

- https://launchpad.net/~awstools-dev/+archive/awstools .

Neither of those have [cloudwatch tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2534) yet. These can easily be packaged.  If you're interested, I'm sure there are some people that would help you get started.